# Camel-http httpclient timeout from exchange headers

Tags: apache-camel

I have a http component in my route in which I want to pass timeout value from exchange header's.
    http://foo.com?httpClient.soTimeout=5000

How can we do this in Spring DSL.

Is is possible to do something like:

```
<to uri="http://foo.com?httpClient.soTimeout=${in.headers.timeout}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, `<to>` DSL will create the endpoint and the producer before any exchange is received and for HTTP component SO_TIMEOUT is not a parameter that you can change in runtime (here's [a list of what you can change](https://camel.apache.org/http.html#HTTP-MessageHeaders)).

That being said, if you are using Camel 2.16+ you can easily do it with [Dynamic To endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html#MessageEndpoint-DynamicTo). In your case that would be:

```
<toD uri="http://foo.com?httpClient.soTimeout=${in.headers.timeout}"/>
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use the [Dynamic Recipient List EIP](https://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html#RecipientList-DynamicRecipientList):

```
<setHeader headerName="theHeader">
    <simple>http://foo.com?httpClient.soTimeout=${in.headers.timeout}</simple>        
</setHeader>
<recipientList>
    <header>theHeader</header>
</recipientList>
```

Comment: And if i use Exchange.Http_uri it will still replace my dummy uri in <recipientlist> right?

Comment: Correct, the behavior is the same regardless of where you use HTTP component - in `to`, `toD` or `recipientList`

Comment: Thanks .I was able to add timeout this way.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this but what if you have more params?
`http://someUrl.com/data?param1=123,param2=abc` Where to I put the `?httpClient.soTimeout`?

Comment: Have you read an introduction to Camel? The number and order of parameters makes no difference, you just treat it as a regular URI :)